# Why these c code not working? Whats wrong with these?

Tags: c

```
#include < stdio.h >

#include < string.h >

int main()

{

unsigned char a;

FILE *P;

P=fopen("mola.txt","r");

while((a=getc(P))!=EOF)

printf("%c",a);

}
```

Whats wrong with these code? When I compile it gives warning "comparison is always true due to limited range of data type." What does that warning mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You are storing the result of `getc` in a `char`**. It should be an `int`. There's also a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html) on it. Also you should check the return value of the `fopen`.

```
P=fopen("mola.txt","r");
if (NULL == P) {
    perror("fopen"):
}
```

Also the `while` looks fishy. Try indenting ?

```
while((a=getc(P)) != EOF)
    printf("%c",a);
```

Comment: its not printing anything just a blank output.

Comment: Try to always use curly braces, it's much cleaner, even for one line. C isn't Python.

Answer (score 1):

It means just what it says

> comparison is always true due to limited range of data type.

The range of the data type in question (the `a`, which is `unsigned char`) is from 0 to 255 (really `UCHAR_MAX`);

The `EOF` value is -1

You are comparing `a` (from 0 to 255) with `-1`

```
(a != -1)
```

**the condition will always be true**

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
int a;
FILE *P;
P=fopen("tryit2.c","r");
while(EOF != (a = fgetc(P))) {
        printf("%c",a);
    }
}
```

You had two problems "getc()" returns an integer not a character. And the while statement had some weird side effects in the original order.

Comment: you did not fix the unsigned char into an int as it should be done! it is just as the OP wrote!

Comment: @Shin -- oops, pasted the wrong version! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

It means the loop will fell into Infinite loop not allowing the program to exit when at `a=getc(p)`.